# How to solve this trig equation , $\tan^{-1}(x) = 1 / \tan (x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Given the equation $$\tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{\tan(x)},\quad x\in[0,2\pi],$$ find the value/values of $x$.

I tried to take $\tan (x)$ for the both sides but the equation had more complicated !

Comment: What is $\tan ^{-1}x $? Is it $\arctan (x) $ or $1/\tan (x) $?

Comment: I doubt if yu can find an analytic solution.  Graphing can get you approximations, which can be refined by Newton's method.

Comment: Where is this coming from ?

Comment: tan−1(x) = arctan (x)

Comment: I wrote it , And it has solutions , but i don't know how to find them handly .

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will not be able to find exact solutions, only numerical. However, as you note, it does have solutions, it has $2n$ solutions in every interval of the form $[-n \pi, n \pi]$.

Comment: In fact, there is a single solution for each $[k\pi, (k+1)\pi]$ interval. Moreover, if $x $ is a solution,  $-x $ is a solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions in the given interval and you can find them only numerically.

[image]